# Real analysis: cauchy/convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence of positive number such that $b_n \to 0$ and suppose that the terms in the sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfy $|a_m−a_n| \leq b_n$ for all $m>n$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges

i worked it out and till
we need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$|a_m-a_n| < \epsilon$ whenever $m,n > n_0$.

Assume $m \leq n$ then $k=n-m$
by using triangular law i reached till

$$|a_m -a_{m+k}|\leq|a_m-a_{m+1}|+|a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}|+....|a_{m+k-1}  - a_{m+k}|$$

Comment: I'm fairly certain this question was posted before, by the same user, but now it's gone (along with the comments therein).

Comment: @hmm: hi, for future reference, when the question itself hasn't changed much, but you have found new clarifications and additions to add, it is better to [edit] your post instead of deleting and re-posting.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon >0$ . $b_n $ converges to zero then there exists $n_0 \in N$ such that $b_n = |b_n| < \epsilon$  $\forall n \geq n_0$.

Let $m,n \in N$ with $m,n \geq n_0$ .  If $m=n$ then $|a_m - a_n| = 0 < \epsilon$

If $m > n$  with $m,n \geq n_0 $then by hypothesis  $|a_m - a_n| \leq b_n < \epsilon$

If $n>m$  with $m,n \geq n_0 $then by hypothesis  $|a_m - a_n| \leq b_m < \epsilon$

Conclusion

$$ |a_m - a_n| < \epsilon  , \forall m,n  \geq n_0$$

Then $a_n$ is Cauchy. Then $a_n$ converges ( in $\mathbb{R}$ all Cauchy sequence is convergent ) .